# "If a group $G$ is cyclic, then it has no proper subgroups." True or false?

Tags: group-theory

I know that the converse is true. What about this implication though?

Comment: Have you thought about any examples...?

Comment: Consider cyclic groups of composite order

Comment: @MikeMiller I tried, but I couldn't get any subgroups that weren't the entire group itself!

Comment: @PeterWoolfitt Thank you so much, it makes so much more sense now!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You know numbers from 0 to 9 form a cyclic group modulo 10. What about the subset consisting of even numbers within that group?

Answer (score 1):

This is false. We can choose $C_2 \cong \{1,a^2\}^\times\in \{1, a, a^2,a^3\}^\times \cong C_4$. This is true, however, if you have a cyclic group of prime order. In the case of the prime order, the order of any subgroup is the prime number itself or 1 (by Lagrange's theorem, that is), so there aren't any proper subgroups.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to look at this: Suppose $G$ is cyclic.  Then, for any $g \in G$, we can consider the subgroup $H = \langle g \rangle$ generated by $g$.  Oftentimes, this subgroup is not the entirety of $G$ (if it is, we call $g$ a generator for $G$.)  In other words, this gives a recipe for generating lots of counterexamples.

Ex. $G = \mathbb{Z}$.  If $g = \pm 1$, then $\langle g \rangle = \mathbb{Z}$, otherwise it's a proper subgroup.

Ex. $G = \mathbb{Z}_n$.  If the greatest common divisor of $k$ and $n$ is greater than one, then $\langle k \rangle$ is proper.

There are lots more examples out there, so pick your favorite group and give it a go!

Answer (score 0):

***False.***  Counterexample(s):  let $m, n > 1$ be integers.  Looks at the additive group $\Bbb Z_{mn}$.  It is a cyclic group generated by $1$; $1^{mn} = 0$, where I have used the multiplicative (exponential) notation for addition in $\Bbb Z_{mn}$:

$a^m = a + a + \ldots + a, \;\; m \; \text{times}. \tag{1}$

Then $1^n$ generates a *proper* subgroup of order $m$.  So $\Bbb Z_{mn}$, though cyclic, has *bona fide* subgroups.